# Android Spinner GetSelection

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I work with Android Project. This is my small code

```
      //SpinAdapter is custom class
        SpinAdapter fromAdapter = new SpinAdapter(getActivity(), 0, new ArrayList<Cities>()); 

          // private Spinner mFrom;
         mFrom.setAdapter(fromAdapter);

         AsyncHttpClient.get(url, null, new HttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onOperationSuccess(String response) {
                Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Cities>>() {
                }.getType();
                ArrayList<Cities> list = new Gson().fromJson(response, listOfTestObject);
                fromAdapter.addAll(list);
               Cities selectionId=mFrom.getSelection()
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {

            }
        });
```

var selectionId is null ? why?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please post more of your source code to add context to your question. What are `fromAdapter` and `{Async-call}`?

Comment: What did you declare `mFrom` as?

Comment: I don't see any `getSelection()` method for `Spinner` here in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html). You could use `getSelectedItem()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Spinner you need to use getSelectedItem(), not getSelection()

You can get the string with getSelectedItem().toString()